# Google Maps C++ api

Tags: c++, google-maps

Is there a c++ api to show the position of a moving vehicle on Google Maps both in map and satellite view? The input data would be the geographical coordinate of the vehicle.
I know an api for c# called GMaps.Net and I wonder if there is an api for c++ too.

Comment: Google maps API is javascript, so I'm not sure what the C# code actually does. [I have implemented quite a bit of "set markers at this location, but not sure how you'd do a marker that moves -other than redrawing it every so often].

Comment: Not C++, but [here is an example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html) that animates a marker along a polyline retrieved from the [Google Maps API v3 DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions). If you have the coordinates of the vehicle, you can just display the marker there.

Comment: @Mats it's safe to assume the javascript API uses another HTTP-based API underneath the covers. I'd imagine the C# library and its ilk are wrappers around that.

Comment: See answers for this posted question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886444/integrating-google-maps-with-c-program and see as well [Google Maps Platform Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi if i where you I would start to use the free and very complete Google Maps Control project which wraps Google Maps API as ASP.NET Custom Control, providing an easy and fast way of adding Google Maps in your ASP.NET pages with "Zero-Written-JavaScript" code.  ASP.NET Google Maps Control includes many features (markers, polyline, polygons, directions) and gives you almost all Google Maps API functionality in enjoyable ASP.NET way of coding. You can find and download the control at Nuget at this adress

PM>Install-Package GoogleMapControl