# Integrating Google maps with C++ Program

Tags: c++, google-maps

I am making an artificial intelligence based shortest distance finder between two points in c++ language. My coding for that is complete and working fine. Now I want to integrate it with Google Maps Api. I want to show the shortest distance graphically on google maps exactly same as google maps show directions. I am stuck and can't find any help. I know I have to do socket programming for this. Please guide me with proper steps and coding snippets. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Check out the official api : 
https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/

For interaction with the http api you could use a client such as curl (http://curl.haxx.se/) or maybe boost asio if your are using boost. see this question at SO: [Boost.ASIO-based HTTP client library (like libcurl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251361/boost-asio-based-http-client-library-like-libcurl)

Answer (score 0):

There is a c++ client/ helper available. Disclosure I have not tried it yet.
https://google.github.io/google-api-cpp-client/latest/
Many links seem to be broken (The samples directory link). So I'm not sure how well supported it is but it looks like it might be helpful.
The description page is at :
https://google.github.io/google-api-cpp-client/latest/start/installation.html
IF that fails there are samples in other languages that you may have to translate by hand. (better than nothing)
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/